# How to make COUNT(*) query faster

Tags: postgresql, performance, count, distinct

I have `table1` which contains around `900k` line of records, and `table2` around `500k rows` and `26 columns`. [sample table](https://dbfiddle.uk/5FaboJ3e)

I want to update `table1` with total of `unique combinations` from `table2`

Tried with different type of counts, but still the performance is **extremally slow**. Is there any alternative options to improve the performance please?

`query #1`, the completion time for just 10 lines is `1 min 47 secs`.

```
do $$ 
declare 
  rec record;
  current_joins text;
  current_result int;
begin for rec in (select joins from table1  where line<=10) loop
     select rec.joins into current_joins;
     execute format('select count(*) from (select 1 from table2 group by %1$s) as some_alias;', current_joins) into current_result;
     update table1  set result = current_result where joins=current_joins;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

`query #2`, the completion time for just 10 lines is `1 min 48 secs`

```
do $$ 
declare 
  rec record;
  current_joins text;
  current_result int;
begin for rec in (select joins from table1  where line<=10) loop
     select rec.joins into current_joins;
     execute format('select count(*) from (select 1 from table2 group by %1$s having count(*)>=1) as some_alias;', current_joins) into current_result;
     update table1 set result = current_result where joins=current_joins;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

`query #3`, the completion time for just 10 lines is `1 min 52 secs`

```
do $$ 
declare 
  rec record;
  current_joins text;
  current_result int;
begin for rec in (select joins from table1 where line<=10) loop
     select rec.joins into current_joins;
     execute format('select count(distinct (%1$s)) from table2', current_joins) into current_result;
     update table1 set result = current_result where joins=current_joins;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

`query #4`, the completion time for just 10 lines is `1 min 55 secs`

```
do $$ 
declare 
  rec record;
  current_joins text;
  current_result int;
begin for rec in (select joins from table1 where line<=10) loop
     select rec.joins into current_joins;
     execute format('select count(*) from (select distinct (%1$s) from table2) as temp', current_joins) into current_result;
     update table1 set result = current_result where joins=current_joins;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

`other option`, tried with `Microsoft Excel`, the completion time for just 10 lines is `<10 secs` which is much faster than all the above sql codes, but still slow with 500k data

```
=LET(A,Data!$C$2:$AB$12,B,ROWS(A),C,FILTERXML("<A><B>"&SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","</B><B>")&"</B></A>","//B"),ROWS(UNIQUE(INDEX(A,SEQUENCE(B),TRANSPOSE(C)))))
```

Comment: Use `auto_explain` to get execution plans for the queries in your code, thhey will show why it is slow.

Comment: You're doing it iteratively in a loop. Have you tried with bulk operations? Either a single update or an insert ... into followed by updates from the temp table?

Comment: @  ewramner No I haven't tried, appreciate if you could assist with suggested options please.

Comment: @  Laurenz Albe can you please advise how to use `auto_explain`?